# xlswrite: Showing variable name in sheet name or somewhere

Tags: python, matlab

1. I am using xlswrite.

I am putting lots of variables into different sheets of one xlsx file.

One variable for one sheet.

So I want to put the name of the variable as the name of the sheet.

I couldn't find any command which does this. So perhaps this should be done by coding some python and having one line in matlab which calls that py file.

2. If this is impossible, I will just try to put the name of the variable in the first row. However, when the variable has more than 1 column, then it says vertcat doesn't work.

   xlswrite('test.xlsx',vertcat('A', [1 3; 1 2]))

What should I do?

======================

A follow-up question

I coded the following based on Suever's answer.

```
function xlswr(file_name,varargin)
xlswrite(file_name,varargin{i},inputname(i+1))
```

However, when I call this function by

```
xlswr('test.xlsx', A, A(:,2))
```

then A is printed on test.xlsx, but A(:,2) was not.

Whenever the input is not just whole name like A, but some part of the variable, then it doesn't print it out.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for your issue is that you're attempting to vertically concatenate a string that is `1 x 1` with data that is `2 x 2` so you obviously are going to have a dimension mis-match.

If you want to specify the sheet name, then simply use the [third input](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlswrite.html#inputarg_sheet) to `xlswrite` to specify the name of the sheet as a string.

```
xlswrite('test.xlsx', [1 3; 1 2], 'A')
```

Alternately, if you want to include text and numeric data, you can always pass a cell array rather than a numeric array. This will place strings and numbers *into the same sheet*.

```
xlswrite('test.xlsx', vertcat({'A', 'B'}, num2cell([1 3; 1 2])));
```

Comment: Thank you! However the third input to xlswrite is range of input. How does this work?

Comment: @user42459 What version of MATLAB are you using?

Comment: I don't remember but never mind. It works very well. Thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you again. I posted a follow-up question. Could you please take a look?

Comment: @user42459 The code that you've posted isn't valid. What exactly do you expect the `A(:,2)` to do? The third input should be a string.

Comment: I just hope the 2nd column of A is printed out to the 2nd sheet of test.xlsx, and the whole A is printed out to the 1st sheet of test.xlsx

Comment: @user42459 You have to call `xlswrite` twice. `xlswrite('file.xlsx', A, 1); xlswrite('file.xlsx', A(:,2), 2);`

Comment: I mean, how can I set the name of the sheet as "A(:,2)" ?

Comment: @user42459 Make it a string? `xlswrite('file.xlsx', A(:,2), 'A(:,2)')`

Comment: I am actually using a separate function xlswr to print them out (as can be written in the follow-up question). How should I write the function xlswr to set the sheet name as A(:,2) when the variable being printed out is A(:,2)? It seems weird to me that "A" is being put to sheet name but "A(:,2)" isn't.

Comment: @user42459 I can't speak for your custom function. Maybe post a new question as that is outside of the scope of this question.